# simple javascript form validation submit doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Why my simple javascript validation not working. I want to check if the default text is same as default value (Keyword(s)), then submit the form with empty parameter.

```
<form method="get" id="search_form" action="http://somesampleurl.com" onsubmit="return validation();">
<input name="s_rawwords" value="Keyword(s)" id="search_field" class="search_field" type="text">
<input name="s_freeloc" value="City, State or Zip" id="search_field2" class="search_field" type="text">
<input value="" id="search_button" type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validation(){
        var search_key = document.getElementById("search_field").value
        alert(search_key);
        if(search_key =="Keyword(s)"){
            alert("step2");
            search_key = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: return `true` or `false` and it would work

Comment: Sorry Guys. It did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function validation(){
    var search_key = document.getElementById("search_field").value;
    alert(search_key);
    if(search_key =="Keyword(s)"){
        alert("step2");
        document.getElementById("search_field").value = "";
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function never returns `true` or `false`, so it doesn't validate anything. Return `false` when the inputs are invalid and you don't want the form to be submitted.

See here [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)